# Creating variable names from parameters

Tags: c++, c, reflection

Is it possible to create a list of variables with a parameter in the name?
Something like this:

```
for(n=0; n< val; n++)
  int var'n'=0;
```

Comment: No. At best, you can use a `std::map` to map string keys to actual objects. An array is all you probably need, though.

Comment: You could use Boost.PP to generate however many `var0, var1, var2...` you need if `val` is known then, but that's really much worse than an array.

Comment: In C or C++?  They are different languages.

Comment: You are trying to invent arrays, aren't you?

Comment: Even if it was possible, the variables you've declared would not be carried out of the `for` block. They would be destroyed as soon as the `for` ended...

Answer (score 2):

Usually, no.

Variables names must be fixed at compile-time. They cannot depend on run-time input. So if the `n` in your example is input (say, from the user), what you want cannot be done.

If you know `n` statically, you could do tricks with the preprocessor, or templates, or both, but you probably don't want to: How would you get to use your `n` variables?